# Diagonalization of a hermitian matrix?

Tags: linear-algebra

It is said that any finite-dimensional Hermitian matrix can be diagonalized by a unitary matrix.  But isn't a *special* unitary matrix sufficient?

Am I making a mistake when I say that the phase that makes unitary matrices non-special doesn't do anything when diagonalizing Hermitian matrices?

Comment: You mean how if $\lambda$ is a complex number with modulus $1$ and $U$ is unitary, then $UAU^*=\lambda U A (\lambda U)^*$, so it can be assumed that $\det U=1$ if that were ever more convenient?

Comment: Yes, that's what I mean.  Is that correct?  Or are there cases when  $\lambda$ matters?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, one can always take the unitary matrix diagonalizing a Hermitian matrix to have determinant $1$, by multiplying by a scalar of modulus $1$.

So no, you are not making a mistake.  I guess that because in many contexts such a normalization is not useful, and because it is easy to make the adjustment as needed once the arbitrary unitary case is known, this fact is not said as often.